# How to traverse this ajax response as array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, codeigniter

I am getting the below array as response using ajax in code igniter.

```
 Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [monthly_count] => 3
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [monthly_count] => 1
        )

)
```

//What i have tried so far is

```
$.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Admins/get_monthly_orders",
            type: 'POST',
            //dataType: 'JSON',
            success:function (data) {
                var result = [];
                var array = data;
                console.log(data);
                array.forEach(function(k , v) {
                    var result = v.monthly_count;
                })
                console.log(result);
```

please help me to traverse and get 3, 1
 and i need to get the value of 'monthly_count' like this

```
Array
(
    [0]  =>3


    [1] => 1

)
```

or better something like this

```
[3, 1]
```

my controller code is this

```
public function get_monthly_orders(){
        $monthlyOrders = $this->Admin_model->get_monthly_orders();

        if($monthlyOrders){
            print_r($monthlyOrders);
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: @Andy Please check

Comment: show me your php code.

Comment: also show me get_monthly_orders in Admin_model

Comment: I think it's `data.map(d=>d.monthly_count)` but if it's not then post the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(data,2,undefined));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `print_r($monthlyOrders)` to `echo json_encode( $monthlyOrders );`. This will return it in JSON. It will be much easier to traverse in JS.

Well if you want to traverse it, you can just:

```
let result = [];
array.forEach(el => {
  result.push(el.monthly);
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @adis..i solve it by just using json_encode().